# Wrong scope when using $compile for a child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to conditionally use a child directive inside a parent directive.

I'm using `$compile` to compile a template for a child directive in parent directive's `link` function, and the child directive has its own isolated scope.

The problem is that an `ng-click` on the child directive is invoked in the *parent scope* when the child directive's element is clicked.

Here is an SSCCE:

```js
var app = angular.module("test", []);

app.directive("parentDirective", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.append('!');
      scope.foo = function() {
        alert('parent foo');
      };
      var childTemplate = "<div child-directive ng-click='foo()'>Child directive</div>";
      element.append($compile(childTemplate)(scope));
    }
  };
});

app.directive("childDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.foo = function() {
        alert('child foo!');
      };
      element.append('!');
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <div parent-directive>Parent directive</div>
</div>
```

The `ng-click=foo()` should invoke `foo` from the child scope, however it's invoking the parent `foo`. If you click `Child directive!` div you get `Parent foo` alert.

Why is that so and how can I make it work as expected?

Comment: You need to make ```scope:true``` to get the parent scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this issue is regarding **scope of compiling** the template.

check this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/30kwGCuX2nlwe9L0h0Sp?p=preview)

`alert('init parent directive -1');` will called then the `alert('init child directive');` and finally `alert('init parent directive-2');`

that means in `line 20` in the plunker example, parent directive link function create a `child-directive` but the that directive compile against the **`parent directive scope` not the `scope of the child directive`**, so the `$compile()` can only see anything inside the `parent directive scope`cant see about the `child scope`.

if you need to attach `child scope` then you have to compile it inside the `child directive`. or better to use `template` or `templateUrl` in the `child directive`.

Comment: I don't understand, it works when you changed the child directive *not to use* isolated scope, and that's the only change needed to make it work, it seems. Parent directive is still compiling the child directive.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("test", []);

app.directive("parentDirective", function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    template: "<div ng-click='foo()'>Parent directive!</div>", //You can use templateUrl as well
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.foo = function() {
        alert('parent foo');
      };
      var childTemplate = "<child-directive/>";
      element.append($compile(childTemplate)(scope));
    }
  };
});

app.directive("childDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    template: "<div ng-click='foo()'>Child directive!</div>",
    scope: {},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.foo = function() {
        alert('child foo!');
      };
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
  <parent-directive/>
</div>
```

Try this